# Positioning the background-repeat Property

Tags: html, css, styles, background-image

I have this drop-down button, which is styled using this css:

```
.styled-select {
        background: url(resources/img/selector.png) no-repeat right;
        background-color: white;
        width: 305px;
        height: 42px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
    }
```

The result is shown in this picture:

[image]

As you see, using `no-repeat right` made the `selector.png` go to the right end. I want to know if there is any solution to position that arrow in order to shift it a little to the left as in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `background-position` property `value` like this:

```
background: url(resources/img/selector.png) no-repeat top 96%;
```

Comment: I will, I don't know why it says that I should wait 6 minutes :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use right propety like this

```
.styled-select {
    background: url(resources/img/selector.png) no-repeat right;
    background-color: white;
    width: 305px;
    height: 42px;
    position: relative;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
}
```

Comment: this will give a right space to the whole box, not only the arrow.

Comment: Did you try whole padding property?

Comment: Solved with background-position as suggested by G.L.P. thanks for your help.